# Base URL + user input = combined url

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

What I am trying to figure out is clicking on a button to where an input field appears, and the user can input numbers/characters to go to a subpage.  Example would be: The button goes to "website.com" and the user inputs "852147", the button would take the user to "website.com/852147".

Comment: that would require some javascript - hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

you can change the pathname by adding the url

```
<input type="text" id="inputid">
    <button onclick="window.location.pathname=document.getElementById('inputid').value">
```

or

use window.location.href ="website.com/"+document.getElementById('inputid').value"

hope it helps

thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="locNum" />
<button id="clickme">
Click Me
</button>

<script>
function fire() {
  var site = "http://website.com/";
  var locNum = document.getElementById("locNum").value;
  window.location.href = site + locNum;
  console.log(locNum);
}

document.getElementById("clickme").onclick = fire;
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use query string. Hope this will work for you.

Comment: This isn't a complete answer to the problem.